# Fceabook PHP SDK valid access token

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, facebook-php-sdk, token

I have search over and over again and I can't seem to find an answer. What am I doing wrong?

My error is FacebookApiException [ 0 ]: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

*EDIT* Just to add. This worked once or twice, but never in succession.

```
require_once('media/fb/facebook.php');
        $app_id = '123456';
        $app_secret = '123456';
        $my_url = 'mysiteurl';

        $config = array(
            'appId' => $app_id,
            'secret' => $app_secret,
            'fileUload' => 'false');

        $facebook = new Facebook($config);
        $user = $facebook->getUser();
        if($user) {
            try {
                $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
            } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
                error_log($e->getType());
                error_log($e->getMessage());
            }    
        } else {
            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'  => $my_url));
            header("Location:" . $login_url);
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET'); 
        }
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does your error come from this line:  `$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');` at the bottom?

The header function will re-direct the user to Facebook login page which will cause the browser to refresh. You won't get the user's access token immediately after that. You need to wait until the user is redirected back to your website to get the access token. You need to set `$my_url` to point to the same page of the codes you wrote here.

Comment: Yes, that is where I get the error. I have tried that before by leaving the parameters empty for the login url. This defaults it to redirect to the same page. I still get the same error.

Comment: You need to read more about how Facebook authentication process works. I think you have some mis-understanding on the concept.